# Synchronize headerless messages

Tags: robot-state-publisher, message-filters, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to synchronize messages without headers. I know synchronization can be done with `message_filters` when they have timestamps, but these messages are the simple std_msgs/Float32 kind. Can this be done?

My goal is to receive two angle positions from two motors that actuate the same joint, in order to send a sensor_msgs/JointState message regarding the entire joint.

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152681/synchronize-headerless-messages/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do this properly, there is no way around adding a Header to the messages. Otherwise you have no information at all about when the messages are created, only when they are received by your node. There might be different delays etc. on the two topics, so that is going to fail in a lot of cases.

If you have no way of modifying the publisher so that it includes a Header, the only thing you can do is wait until you've received one message on each topic and then pretend they are synchronized, like this:

```
msg1 = msg2 = null;

motor1_callback(msg) {
   msg1 = msg;
   check_and_process();
}

motor2_callback(msg) {
   msg2 = msg;
   check_and_process();
}

check_and_process() {
   if (msg1 != null && msg2 != null) {
       do_something(msg1, msg2);
       msg1 = msg2 = null;
   }
}
```

Take-home message: add a Header to your messages, modify your publisher and use `message_filters` if at all possible.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-14**:
Thank you for your reply, that is what I was doing now. I was hoping for a different solution but I understand what you mean. This perhaps deserves a separate topic, but my goal is to publish a joint state with pitch and yaw. Should I make one joint for both rotations, or one joint per rotation?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-04-14**:
You should make two `revolute` joints, because that captures your degrees of freedom correctly. If you wanted to only make one joint, you would have to use a `floating` joint, and that would be incorrect (you don't have 6 DoF).

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-14**:
Thank you very much for your reply! I will get to it :)